# Ember JS | Qunit - Phantom JS Set called on already destroyed object

Tags: ember.js, phantomjs, ember-qunit

I am running into this weird problem, where Ember Qunit Tests pass successfully when I run a single module.
But they fail when I run all modules test cases.

The failure error looks like this

> set called on already destroyed object.

Can someone point me in the correct direction to get this fixed please?

Comment: Could you share more info (how many tests are in the total suite, what does the average teardown look like, what the test in question looks like)

Comment: can you please explain more? Maybe a sample of how the tests look like?

Comment: The problem drills down to the fact that Ember.service is not calling its Will Destroy method for some weird reason!